# make can't determine implicit rules when prerequisite has no suffix or prefix?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a simple make file where I just want to take each .c file in a folder and compile them separately and run them dumping the output to a text file with the same filename.

```
%.txt: %
    ./$< > $@
```

For example if I have `p1.c` there is an implicit rule that I can make `p1` executable file from `p1.c` and then my rule specifies you can make `p1.txt` by executing `p1` however this does not seem to work:

```
$ make p1.txt
make: *** No rule to make target `p1.txt'.  Stop.
```

I can however make the executable explicitly then make the text file (since the implicit rule works when it is only 1 step and the text file works when the executable is already present)

```
$ make p1
cc     p1.c   -o p1
$ make p1.txt
./p1 > p1.txt
```

If I also name the files out explicitly in the makefile everything works fine:

```
%.txt: %
    ./$< > $@
p1.txt: p1
```

This works for `p1` but I'd like it to just work for all c files in my folder and writing some form of `for each` just so make sees the dependencies explicitly seems silly.

Looking at [the documentation for implicit rule lookup](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rule-Search.html) and from what I understand when the dependency is explicitly mentioned in the file step 5 determines:

> (If a file name is mentioned in the makefile as a target or as an explicit dependency, then we say it ought to exist.)
> If all dependencies exist or ought to exist, or there are no dependencies, then this rule applies.

when it is explicitly `p1.txt: p1` means the dependency `p1` ought to exist and there exists an implicit rule to do so.  When it is not explicitly there the only part I am unsure about is what "terminal" means in step 6.1

> If the rule is terminal, ignore it and go on to the next rule

What would I need to specify so that I can just use the executable generated from a .c file as a dependency?

I am using `GNU Make 3.81` if this happens to be a version specific bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the official GNU website and read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) there, you'll see that it has an [extensive index](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Concept-Index.html).  If you look through that index to find "terminal rule", it will send you to the section on [Using Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html).

This will lead you to understand that your rules are not terminal (because they do not use double-colon definitions).  But make treats match-anything rules (rules where the target is just `%`, which the built-in rule is) specially, which means your attempt cannot work.